# Localhost Unable to POST

Tags: php, xampp, fopen

So I have working version of a graph that I made with the Google Charts API, and I post the Chart data/configuration like this:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array('http' => array(
      'method' => 'POST',
      'content' => http_build_query($chart))));
    fpassthru(fopen($url, 'r', false, $context));
```

It works great! But when I check it out on my local windows box and try to run it with Xampp I get this error:

> Warning:
>   fopen(http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chid=982f36)
>   [function.fopen]: failed to open
>   stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0
>   400 Bad Request in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\graph\image.php
>   on line 226

I have had a look at my php.ini file on the localbox and it has this under fopen wrappers:

```
; Whether to allow the treatment of URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-fopen
allow_url_fopen = On

; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-include
allow_url_include = Off

; Define the anonymous ftp password (your email address). PHP's default setting
; for this is empty.
; http://php.net/from
;from="john@doe.com"

; Define the User-Agent string. PHP's default setting for this is empty.
; http://php.net/user-agent
;user_agent="PHP"

; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
; http://php.net/default-socket-timeout
default_socket_timeout = 60

; If your scripts have to deal with files from Macintosh systems,
; or you are running on a Mac and need to deal with files from
; unix or win32 systems, setting this flag will cause PHP to
; automatically detect the EOL character in those files so that
; fgets() and file() will work regardless of the source of the file.
; http://php.net/auto-detect-line-endings
;auto_detect_line_endings = Off
```

What could be the problem here? Any advice would help Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually working just fine from the PHP side.  Take that URL and paste it into your web browser:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chid=982f36

You'll get a `400 Bad Request` error page from Google saying `The Chart API request contains no valid parameters`.  I don't know anything about the Google charts API, but it seems like you must not be passing the parameters to Google correctly.

Comment: @Pete - regardless judging by the error, it seems like the `fopen` is working as it should, and your PHP settings are correct.  The problem must be something else in the data you are posting to the charts API.

Comment: @Pete never the less, a status code of [400](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1) indicates that Google is rejecting your URL/submission.

Comment: This is currently working on the client's server, I did an svn checkout from the client's repository, and it doesn't work out of the box, perhaps something else is the problem thanks guys